Using Graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ to Find $\delta$

Hello,
This is a question I was assigned for homework and I am struggling to find a correct answer. The question states "Use the graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ below to find a number δ such that $|f(x)−0.25|<0.1$ whenever $0<|x−4|<\delta$." On the y-axis, there are three points. The first is .25 and the other two are a distance of .1 away, at .35 and .15 respectively. The x-axis has corresponding points for each on the y-axis, they are blank at .35 and .15 and 4 at .25. The points together are $(4, 0.25)$; $(x, 0.15)$; and $(x, 0.35)$.
I included a picture of the graph at the top of this post.
I have attempted to solve with 1/x=.35 and 1/x=.15 and subtracting the result from 4, but the website will not take a rounded answer.
Any help at all will be appreciated, Thank you!

You might have a $\delta$ in mind, then rounding down your $\delta$ would give another answer that satisfies the question.

"But the website will not take a rounded answer" ... so don't round? I would expect the system is expecting the exact distance from 4 to the closest of those red points.

I've tried rounding the answer and not rounding the answer I get, it says I'm wrong each time so I don't know what it's looking for.

What are the $\delta$ answers you have tried submitting?

I have tried 1.142857143, the result of subtracting 1/x=.35 from 4; and 10.666... the result of 1/x=.15 added to 4.

@Squishy698 $|x-4|$ represents the distance to 4; so you might either have to do $4-x$ or $x-4$ to evaluate $|x-4|$ (since you always want a positive result), but you're never doing $x+4$. (And I would echo other comments that you can almost surely type a fraction in that box.)

To be picky, your $1.142~857~143 > 4-\frac1{.35}$, so for example when $x=4-1.142~857~142~9 = 2.857~142~857~1$, this $x$ fails the question with $f(x) > 0.35$. That's why I suggested to round down $\delta$.

Why not just try $\delta=1/10^{1000}$? Should work

@peterwhy $4-\frac {1}{.35}$ doesn't work because .35 and .15 are Y-values, they can't be substituted for X. my statements looked like $4-\sqrt[-1]{.35}$ and $4-\sqrt[-1]{.15}$. Neither passes the first test though, $|f(x)-0.25)|<0.1$

$4-\sqrt[-1]{.35}$ is a possible $\delta$ value, but not a substitute for $x$. The $x$s come from $0< \lvert x-4\rvert < 4-\sqrt[-1]{.35}$, and the (exclusive) lower endpoint is $x > \sqrt[-1]{.35}$.

The solution to this specific question was $4-\frac{1}{.35}$. Formatting was very specific for the website I was using.
To get this answer, I set $f(x)$ equal to the points on the Y-axis, factored, then subtracted the answer from four.
$\frac{1}{x}=.35$
$X=\frac{1}{.35}$
Solution:
$4-\frac{1}{.35}$

Hint: First observe that solving for $1/x = .35$ and subtracting from $4$ will work but not solving for $1/x = .15$ and so on. And also check on which side you have to round.
Edit: you can also check if the input accepts (exact) fraction.
